# Update DataGridview Frequently (1/second) and maintain scroll state and user interactivity

Tags: c#, winforms, performance, data-binding, datagridview

I have a DataGridview that I am updating from an external event that comes to me about once per second. While I managed to capture the scroll positions; the DataGridView tends to reset itself in the display showing row 1 through last visible column - yet my scroll bars maintain position. Also I would like my DataGridView to allow for more user interactivity , but it is clunky at best. The updating also causes my application to consume 25% of the CPU time (all it is doing is capturing the event and updating the grid (30 rows of 10 columns , mostly integers and floats.

**My 2 questions are:**

1: How to enforce scroll & gridview position on updates?

2: How to update the DataGridView efficiently in order to maintain user interactivity while updating the source frequently (@ 1/second)?
(Right now my code consumes 25% of CPU to do this task.) Dell Precision M4700 24GB ram. )

My Code:

```
void UpdateBayGridview(System.Collections.Generic.List<BAY> bay)
{
    int vscroll = dgBinContent.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;
    int hscroll = dgBinContent.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;

    this.BayTable.BeginLoadData();

    DataTable dtupdates = bay.ToDataTable<BAY>();
    DataColumn[] pkUPdateColumn = { dtupdates.Columns["ID"] };
    dtupdates.PrimaryKey = pkUPdateColumn;

    DataColumn[] pkColumn = { this.BayTable.Columns["ID"] };
    this.BayTable.PrimaryKey = pkColumn;
    this.BayTable.Merge(dtupdates);
    this.BayTable.EndLoadData();
    schemachange = false;

    bsBays.ResetBindings(schemachange);

    // Set the scroll positions
    if (vscroll < 0)
        vscroll = 0;

    if (hscroll < 0)
        hscroll = 0;

    dgBinContent.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = vscroll;
    dgBinContent.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex = hscroll;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was multi threaded and not properly controlling the threads along with having a bound datasource that I was trying to merge. So things were getting hit twice or out of sequence - so I revised the code to use a threaded binding list, with a dictionary merge scheme, along with an Invoke extension method that allows me to update the GUI.

The code works quite nicely. I use an async task method to call it - fire and forget.

```
    private async void WCF_ReceiveProductList(object sender, List<iSortData.PRODUCTS> e)
    {
        VScrollPosition["PRODUCT"] = dgProductContent.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex;   
        HScrollPosition["PRODUCT"] = dgProductContent.FirstDisplayedScrollingColumnIndex;

        if (e.Count > 0)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TaskBased_UpdateProductList(e)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

    }

     private void TaskBased_UpdateProductList(List<iSortData.PRODUCTS> productlist)
    {
        lock (_synclock)
        {
            this.ProductBindingList = MergeListWithBindingProductList(productlist, ProductBindingList);
        }

        dgProductContent.InvokeEx(ProductContent =>
            {
                ProductContent.Refresh();
                ProductContent.ClearSelection();
            });

        SetGridScrollPositions(dgProductContent, "PRODUCT");
    }


   private Utility.Collections.ThreadedProductdingList<PRODUCT> MergeListWithBindingProductList(List<PRODUCT> list1, Utility.Collections.ThreadedProductdingList<PRODUCT> list2)
    {
        lock (_synclock)
        {
            var revdict = list1.ToDictionary(b => b.Name);

            if (list2.Count < 1)
            {
                PRODUCTS[] list3 = revdict.Values.ToArray();
                for (int x = 0, list3Length = list3.Length; x < list3Length; x++)    
                {
                    list2.Add(list3[x]); // index out of range ??(impossible) but happens if not properly threaded i.e. no (_synclock).
                }

            }
            else
            {
                for (int n = 0, list2Count = list2.Count; n < list2Count; n++)
                {
                    if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(list2[n].Name)) && revdict.ContainsKey(list2[n].Name))
                    {
                        list2[n] = revdict[list2[n].Name];
                    }
                }
            }
            return list2;
        }
    }
```